# SDL2 target texture background alpha

Tags: c, sdl-2, texture2d, render-to-texture

I want create to create a texture target with alpha background. Is it possible in SDL2?

So when I compose, for example 10 textures to one, then between textures appear some piece of other textures, which I have rendered before.

What I want to achieve:

http://s17.postimg.org/7zblcb873/want.png

And what is possible to do:
http://s14.postimg.org/9w4sajslt/possible_Do.png

I create the texture this way:

```c
    SDL_Texture*texture=SDL_CreateTexture(win->renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
    SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, w, h);   
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(win->renderer, texture);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(win->renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(win->renderer, NULL);
    SDL_RenderCopy(win->renderer,texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(win->renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    // here i copy the sprites to texture and then change the renderer to window
```

Comment: Why you don't just make background of the texture transparent instead of purple?

Comment: but it is not solve my problem. The purple is on background off first target texture the floor and second target texture is compose from walls and where is the alpha there are appear segments from preceding target texture

Comment: Then, I don't fully understand your problem. You want to cover whole target texture with sprites? Are you sure that you draw things at proper coordinates?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat he might have a floor texture and wall texture of the same size but the wall might have transparent pixels. In that case he could render over the whole texture.

Comment: No I want cover some part of target texture with sprites and where is not sprite there are alpha. I have one target texture which representing floor thats fine and second target texture where is wall and there is problem becouse the space between walls i want transparency but when i create target then texture is not full transparent

Comment: In general i want create  texture where i copy some sprites and where is not sprite there are transparency like a gimp in Work  with layer the whole target texture is layer and that texture can have some transparency color and there are possible compose more layer (target textures)

Comment: I have an idea. Try to call `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);` for every texture you're drawing to target.

Comment: yep i do it. I show next one example first picture is brush1 thats one texture, second brush2 and third img is brush2 but it is wrong becouse there are apear some tiles from brush1 this tiles automatic appears when i write this  SDL_Texture*texture=SDL_CreateTexture(win->renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888, 
    SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, w, h); 
Why i want the transparency whole texture after create http://s28.postimg.org/4taya1jot/next_img.png

Comment: And in this img show , What I want to achieve: it is texture compose from 2 rect first rect is black and second rect is red and where is not rect there are transparency this representing white. http://s17.postimg.org/mh1o84ha7/schem.png